# Problem on grouping when the groups have different names.

Tags: combinatorics

There are two groups in a question paper the two groups are A & B. We have 4 different questions which have to divide into two groups equally.
So, here the groups are predefined and if we use the formula of groups then we have to consider the groups are identical, and that will eliminate cases with different combinations.
And if we use the idea that we have to divide a certain number of different items into different persons then we will get all the different combinations that are possible.
So, please tell me what should I do if I encounter predefined groups like this one (like the ones that are predefined).

Comment: Please write a more concrete example.  As it stands, it is hard to discern what you are asking.